# Linking HTML Checkbox to Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How could I link a checkbox from HTML into java script ? I have built the checkbox in HMTL like so : 
 `<label><b>Response Needed ?</b></label>
    <input id="Check" type="checkbox" >`

When I hit the submit button I need the value to be T (true) or F (false) if its checked or not..

I usually use `getElementById("")` to link things into Javascirpt but cant get this to work!

EDIT: Here is my full Document so you can see how its works :

```
`

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 

 </head>

<body>

<form id="OTA">

    <label><b>IMEI:</b></label>
<input type="text" name="ID" id="IMEI" maxlength="15"> 

    <label><b>AT Command:</b></label>
    <input id="Command" type="text">

    <label><b>Response Needed ?</b></label>
    <input id="Check" type="checkbox" >


</form>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="showInput();"><br />
    <p><span id='display'></span> </p> 

    <script language="JavaScript">
function showInput() {

    var message_entered = ">RSP=" + document.getElementById("Check").checked + ";ID=" +  document.getElementById("IMEI").value + ";" + document.getElementById("Command").value + "<";

    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = message_entered;

}
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I need to change the values of the checkbox to T and F when checked or not.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is some javascript

```html
 <form id="OTA">
    
        <label><b>IMEI:</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="ID" id="IMEI" maxlength="15"> 
    
        <label><b>AT Command:</b></label>
        <input id="Command" type="text">
    
        <label><b>Response Needed ?</b></label>
        <input id="Check" type="checkbox" >
    
    
    </form>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="showInput();"><br />
        <p><span id='display'></span> </p> 
    
        <script language="JavaScript">
    function showInput() {
         var test=null;
    var obj=document.getElementById("Check").checked;
    obj?test='t':test='f';
      var message_entered = ">RSP=" +test+  document.getElementById("IMEI").value + ";" + document.getElementById("Command").value + "<";
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = message_entered;
    
    }
        </script>
```

Comment: Note...If you don't type anything,,you will see you "t" or "f" values showing alone

Comment: Welcome..Happy Holidays

Answer (score 1):

Well... if you want to check whether a checkbox is checked or not (True or False), you can use `document.getElementById("Check").checked`

Example

```
if (document.getElementById("Check").checked) 
    console.log("checked");
else 
    console.log("not checked");
```

Comment: Okay thanks. I need the outcome to be T or F.. how could I go about changing that ?

Comment: What do you mean "the outcome"?

Comment: as in I need to change True and False to T and F

Comment: Yes but in what way? How are you using the "T" and "F"? Given the above example, you know whether the checkbox is checked or not, so you can at that point set anything you like to "T" or "F" and return it. I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: okay, usually when the checkbox is checked and submit is hit it would display True.. instead I need it to display T or F if its not checked

Comment: How are you displaying 'True'? How are you obtaining that value?

Comment: Im not sure. Ive posted my whole document if that helps, thanks

Answer (score 0):

On your submit button call some javascript method like below:

```
<form action="someAction" method="post"  onSubmit="javascript:validate()">
<input type="hidden" name="checkValue" id="checkValue" value='F'/> <!--Default value is F say -->
<submit></submit>
</form>
```

Now, below is validate function:

```
<script>
function validate(){
  if (document.getElementById("Check").checked){ 
     document.getElementById("checkValue").value = 'T'
  }else{ 
     document.getElementById("checkValue").value = 'F'
  }
}
</script>
```

There is just one disadvantage that you need to have checkbox with name different than original name you wanted as that original name would go to hidden field.

Hope it helps!!